# How can I call an arraylist that I already have loaded with my database inside the XML

Tags: java, zk

I'm using ZK and I have this code that works me statically

```
<zscript>
<![CDATA[
  List tipo_servicios = new ArrayList();
  List tipo_servicios_enc = new ArrayList();
  DTO.Tiposervicio tipo_servicios_select;

  DTO.Tiposervicio tiposervicio = new DTO.Tiposervicio();
  tiposervicio.setId(1);
  tiposervicio.setName("Mustang");
  tiposervicio.setDescripcion("New Mustang 2018");
  tiposervicio.setEstatus('A');
  tipo_servicios.add(tiposervicio);

  void buscarTipoServicios()
  {
    if (keywordBox.getValue() != null && !keywordBox.getValue().trim().equals(""))
    {
      tipo_servicios_enc.clear();
      for (DTO.Tiposervicio tipo_serv : tipo_servicios)
      {
        if (tipo_serv.getName().toLowerCase().contains(keywordBox.getValue().trim().toLowerCase()) || tipo_serv.getName().toLowerCase().contains(keywordBox.getValue().trim().toLowerCase()))
        {
          tipo_servicios_enc.add(tipo_serv);
        }
      }
      binder.loadAll();
    }
  }
]]>
</zscript>
```

It's a search engine

```
void buscarTipoServicios()
```

And I have in my service package my next code that is used to load my array from the database

```
public class ConsultarTipoServicio extends SelectorComposer
{
    private List<Tiposervicio> listaTipoServicio;
    private TiposervicioJpaController tipoServicioJpaController; 
    public ConsultarTipoServicio() throws Exception 
    {
        EntityManagerFactory emf =Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ProyectoLabIIPU");
        tipoServicioJpaController=new TiposervicioJpaController(emf);

        listaTipoServicio= tipoServicioJpaController.findTiposervicioEntities();
    }
    public List<Tiposervicio> getlistaTipoServicio()
    {
      return listaTipoServicio;
    }
}
```

I want somehow to assign to my

```
List tipo_servicios = new ArrayList();
```

The array already loaded from

```
getlistaTypeServicio ()
```

I'm trying something like this but it gives me error

```
  List tipo_servicios = Servicios.ConsultarTipoServicios.getlistaTipoServicio();
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` List tipo_servicios = Servicios.ConsultarTipoServicios.getlista . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class or variable not found: Servicios.ConsultarTipoServicios : at Line: 8 : in file: inline evaluation of: `` List tipo_servicios = Servicios.ConsultarTipoServicios.getlista . . . '' : Servicios .ConsultarTipoServicios .getlistaTipoServicio ( )

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
    consultar = new Servicios.ConsultarTipoServicio();
    List tipo_servicios = consultar.getlistaTipoServicio();
    List tipo_servicios_enc = new ArrayList();
    DTO.Tiposervicio tipo_servicios_select;
```